# How to create (not send) text messages (sms) on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, sms

I have a xml-file which contains exported text messages from Android. I want to import them into my windows phone (8) so that they can be read from the message app.

I read and parsed the xml-file to my c# class.

Now I'm looking for an interface to insert, import or create text messages into my phone (with the exported date-stamp). I only can find how to send messages (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394005(v=vs.105).aspx).

Is there any functionality in the win-phone library? Or is there an other way to import my messages?.

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Import them where? If you have the xml files, you can just parse them and see the content.

Comment: After the import I want to read the messages in the text message app (that app has a ascii smiley as icon which is contained in a bubble).

There exists an app from Microsoft to take all data from android to microsoft but it works only for android 4.0 or greater (so I can't use it). see: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/switch-to-windows-phone/9wzdncrdtcc2

Comment: Do you have the xsd file for the xml format of the message? Why don't you write a parser yourself?

Comment: I don't understand why you try to explain how to parse the xml. That is not the problem. I can't find any library-method to put my text message into the windows phone's text message app.

Comment: I dont believe there is any way to addyou old messages to the text message app on the phone.

Comment: Unfortunetely that is not possible. Each app lives in a sandbox and cannot create/update i info in other's apps. Saying that, you will have no luck with the import of the messages into the native text app

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone unfortunately does not provide an API that allows you to write short messages to the system's message store - backups that don't originate on other Windows Phone devices (and are imported through the cloud backup) can't be imported.